# Error transfer BSON file with 'com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException'

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, hive, bson

I am trying to transfer BSON file into Hive,BSON file is dump from MongoDB,

the mongodump command like

`mongodump -h $host -u $user -p $password -d $db -c $collection -o $output`,
and i used jar like
`add jar mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar;add jar mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.0.jar;add mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar;`

when i execute the hiveSql like

```
    create external table sfim_logs_dump (
        id string
        ,ts bigint
        ,reqts string
        ) 
        row format serde 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.bsonserde' 
        with serdeproperties(
       'mongo.columns.mapping' = '{"id":"_id","ts":"ts","reqts":"reqts"}')
        stored as inputformat 'com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.bsonfileinputformat' 
        outputformat 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.output.hivebsonfileoutputformat' 
        location '$hdfspath'
```

The error like

```
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:
                at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:302)
                at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:263)
                at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:228)
                at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:156)
                at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:98)
                at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:79)
                at com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.BSONSerDe.initialize(BSONSerDe.java:110)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:526)
```

Please help me to fix the problem? What can i do to transfer BSON file into Hive effective?

Comment: BSON is not JSON. You probably ***really*** want something to "connect" to the actual MongoDB data rather than exporting in any form. See [MongoDB Connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) for just one such implementation.

Comment: Please help me to transfer BSON file into Hive,not use something to "connect" to the actual MongoDB.

Comment: You're not doing anything if it's not working. And it's not working because you are attempting to do the wrong thing. Instead of *"trying to fit square pegs"* take the direction shown to you and learn how it's actually done. Which is to use a connector and not the raw BSON dumps.

Comment: I have a lot of BSON file,and BSON file is Tb level.so,i should restore bson file into MongoDB first and then transfer MongoDB data into Hive?i think it's not a good idea.